# TableSorter : surprising Filter results

Tags: tablesorter

With TableSorter, the filter results seems quite surprising.

Let's look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/Ted22/9tBgZ/28/.
Filter the column with >10, wait a bit, than add a 0 to the filter. The result is totally wrong.

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-placeholder="Try >10, wait a bit, then add a 0">Numeric</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>100000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1000000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1000000000</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

The same problem occurs in documentation example about filtering. See [this page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) and try >10 then >100 on column 'Total'.

Comment: Thanks Ted22! You have found yet another due introduced in v2.16... the entire cache was revamped, so this was one remnant that was causing problems. It will be fixed in the next update. See [this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/600) I opened to track it.

Comment: Now fixed in v2.16.3! The next time you find a bug like this, please  open an issue on Github, thanks!